# C# Index is unpredictable when adding controls to a panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have no code to show because this is a problem with me not understanding the behavior of the designer in VS2015 using C#. I have added a series of labels to a panel, so I can iterate through them in code. The problem is, it seems no matter what order I add the labels to the panel, the indexes of the controls make no sense.

Here is a screen shot. The back colored labels to the right are all contained in a separate panel. I have coded the labels to show their index within the panel container.

[image]

These were added one at a time from the bottom up. How can I manually add the labels and still have predictable indexes?

Any help is appreciated.

This is the result after making the labels the same size, renaminging them lbl0, lbl1 etc. and adding them one at a time from top to bottom....

[image]

Comment: Which index are you talking about?  The TabIndex property?

Comment: Please explain what is your problem with 'unpredictable indexes'. In other words, what are you trying to do with those labels that requires a precise indexing?

Comment: Why do you care about the index? You should assign a name to the corntrols you want and use that instead.

Comment: I am iterating through a data grid view which corresponds to the same order as the labels. I would like to be able to reference the labels by panel.Controls[i] , rather than by the name. This works fine, but I can not figure out how to get the labels ordered from 0 to 7, so the wrong values are being assigned to the wrong labels.

Comment: Don't use winforms. It is unpredictable. Try WPF. The layouts are much more logical.

Comment: The Rows of a DataGridView control have a Tag property.  You can put a reference of the corresponding label in there: `dgv.Rows[0].Tag = label1;`

Comment: LarsTech, that is very interesting, and may very well come in handy in the future. However, I am performing calculations on the individual cells of a certain index in each row (columns). I figured it out, well... I got it to work, with a lot of rearranging and renaming of labels. I still don't understand the behavior. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see where controls are added to the control collection if you look in the Form.Designer.cs file, which is part of the class definition for your form.

[image]

Here you will see a section that begins with `// Form`, and under that you will see where it calls `this.Controls.Add();

The items in this list appear in the order in which you dropped them onto the form (at least for me they do). I just copy/pasted 10 labels onto the form, and I see this:

```
// 
// Form1
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 684);
this.Controls.Add(this.label10);
this.Controls.Add(this.label9);
this.Controls.Add(this.label8);
this.Controls.Add(this.label7);
this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
```

At runtime, the controls are found in the collection exactly as you would expect from reading the code above; the last control added is at index `[0]`:

[image]

Now, adding a panel is a slightly different story, but not much. Because the `Panel` is a container object, the labels get added to the `Panel` controls collection:

```
// 
// panel1
// 
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label18);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label17);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label16);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label15);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label14);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label13);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label12);
this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label11);
this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 366);
this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 172);
this.panel1.TabIndex = 13;
```

Note, however, that the behavior is the same. The most recent control is added to the `Controls` collection first, and will be in the `Panel.Controls[0]` position.

Comment: I originally had the controls in a group box with other labels, I added the panel to separate the controls I wanted to iterate through. It is very possible that the order they were originally added to the groupBox is what was messing me up. I didn't think to check the designer code... I am a student and still learning. This solution would have saved me a lot of time. At least I understand the behavior now, thank you!